# Removing a rectangle with color on mouse release

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am developing a game and in some part of my game I want the rectangle to disappear on mouse release. I have placed 26 rectangles in an `arrayList` and remove the particular `rectangle` clicked as the mouse is released. **So if I remove the `fill` methods, the rectangle disappears successfully but if the `fill` methods are there, it does not work anymore.**

Here is my `paint` method:

```
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {  
      super.paintComponent(g);

        Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Rectangles2.class.getResource("background.jpg"));  
        g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);  

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        for (Rectangle s : rectanglesList) {
            g2.draw(s);
        }

        g2.setColor(bColor);                    
        g2.fill(box1);                  
        g2.fill(box2);
        g2.fill(box3);
        g2.fill(box4);
        g2.fill(box5);
        g2.fill(box6);
        g2.fill(box7);
        g2.fill(box8);
        g2.fill(box9);
        g2.fill(box10);
        g2.fill(box11);
        g2.fill(box12);
        g2.fill(box25);
        g2.setColor(wColor);        
        g2.fill(box13);     
        g2.fill(box14);
        g2.fill(box15);
        g2.fill(box16);
        g2.fill(box17);
        g2.fill(box18);
        g2.fill(box19);
        g2.fill(box20);
        g2.fill(box21);
        g2.fill(box22);
        g2.fill(box23);
        g2.fill(box24);
        g2.fill(box26);
    }
```

Here is how I did the removing of the `rectangle` (Just an excerpt):

```
        if (box1.getBounds().contains(x, y)) {
            pickedPanelNum = 0;
            rectanglesList.remove(box1);
            panelsPane.repaint();
        }
```

Here are the values of the `bColor` and `wColor`:

```
Color bColor = Color.BLACK;
Color wColor = Color.WHITE;
```

**NOTE:**
The `pickedPanelNum` is just for assigning an int value and has no connection to the problem.

**I think it is because when I repaint, the fill methods are still there. However I have no idea for an alternate way of painting the rectangles.**

I hope my problem is stated clearly. If you have ideas how I could solve this, please tell me. Thank you!

**UPDATE:**
Here is a shorter, runnable version of my program. (Background image isn't included though):

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Color.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D;

public class Rec extends JComponent
{
    public ArrayList<Rectangle> rectanglesList = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    public int arrx[] = new int[120];
    public int arry[] = new int[120];
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public int xSize = 2000;
    public int ySize = 1000;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int pickedPanelNum = 0;
    public String pickedPanelDash = "";
    public String pickedPanelColor = "";
    Color bColor = Color.BLACK;
    Color wColor = Color.WHITE;
    boolean removedPanel = false;

    public void launchFrame()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for(int x = 0;x<120;x++)
        {
            arrx[x] = rand.nextInt(640);
            arry[x] = rand.nextInt(590);
        }

        Rectangle box1 = new Rectangle(arrx[103],arry[59],80,90);
        Rectangle box2 = new Rectangle(arrx[105],arry[3],80,90);

        rectanglesList.add(box1);
        rectanglesList.add(box2);

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        JPanel panelsPane = new JPanel()
        {
           public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
           {  
              super.paintComponent(g);

                Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Rectangles2.class.getResource("background.jpg"));  
                g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);  

                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

                for (Rectangle s : rectanglesList) {
                    g2.draw(s);
                }

                g2.setColor(bColor);                    
                g2.fill(box1);  
                g2.setColor(wColor);                    
                g2.fill(box2);
            }       
        };

        JPanel rightPane = new JPanel();    

        panelsPane.addMouseListener (new MouseAdapter ()
        {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event)
            {
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();                       
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event)
            {
                if (box1.getBounds().contains(x, y)) {
                    pickedPanelNum = 0;
                    rectanglesList.remove(box1);
                    panelsPane.repaint();
                }
                if (box2.getBounds().contains(x, y)) {
                    pickedPanelNum = 1;
                    rectanglesList.remove(box2);
                    panelsPane.repaint();
                }   
            }
        });

        panelsPane.addMouseMotionListener (new MouseAdapter ()
        {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event)
            {
                Rec obj = new Rec();
                int dx = event.getX() - x;
                int dy = event.getY() - y;

                if (box1.getBounds().contains(x, y)) {
                    box1.x += dx;
                    box1.y += dy;
                    panelsPane.repaint();
                }
                if (box2.getBounds().contains(x, y)) {
                    box2.x += dx;
                    box2.y += dy;
                    panelsPane.repaint();
                }

            x += dx;
            y += dy;

            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {}
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {}
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {}
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {}
        }); 

        panelsPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (800, ySize-315));    
        rightPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (530, ySize-315)); 
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (xSize, ySize));       
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension (xSize, ySize));
        rightPane.setBackground(Color.gray);
        mainPanel.add(panelsPane);
        mainPanel.add(rightPane);
        frame.add(mainPanel);


        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Rec obj = new Rec();
        obj.launchFrame();
    }
}
```

Comment: Use your loop to fill the rectangle as well. When you remove `box1` from the `List`, it just means that it will no longer be draw (by the `for-loop`), but because you're filling it implicit, it continues to be painted.  Also, refrain from loading resources in the paint method, this could degrade the perform of your program

Comment: @MadProgrammer Sadly, it still did not work. Thank you for the response though and for the advice!

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: @MadProgrammer okay I will! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if you remove `box1` from the `List`, there is nothing stopping it from getting filled in your `paintComponent` method, the `for-loop` is only drawing the outline of the rectangles within the list, but you code implicitly fills them anyway.

So, first, get rid of all the `box{n}` variables. Next change the `paintComponent` method...

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    //Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Rectangles2.class.getResource("background.jpg"));
    //g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    for (Rectangle s : rectanglesList) {
        g2.setColor(bColor);
        g2.fill(s);
        g2.setColor(wColor);
        g2.draw(s);
    }
}
```

So, this just uses the `rectanglesList` to first draw the rectangles and the fill them

Then, lets update the `mouseReleased`...

```
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
    // Because the rectangles are painted in order, the later
    // rectangles are painted over the eailer ones, so, we reverse
    // the list so we can check for the higher positioned
    // rectangles
    List<Rectangle> copy = new ArrayList<>(rectanglesList);
    Collections.reverse(copy);
    for (Rectangle r : copy) {
        if (r.contains(event.getPoint())) {
            rectanglesList.remove(r);
            break;
        }
    }
    event.getComponent().repaint();
}
```

Okay, this is little more funky, but basically, we reverse the list of rectangles (because those rectangles that appear later in the list are painted over those that appear before them) and checks to see if the mouse was clicked within any one of them.  The moment we find a match, we break out of the loop and repaint the component which generated the event

And, because it's nice to see this stuff running, a complete example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Rec extends JComponent {

    public ArrayList<Rectangle> rectanglesList = new ArrayList<Rectangle>();
    public int arrx[] = new int[120];
    public int arry[] = new int[120];
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    public int xSize = 2000;
    public int ySize = 1000;
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int pickedPanelNum = 0;
    public String pickedPanelDash = "";
    public String pickedPanelColor = "";
    Color bColor = Color.BLACK;
    Color wColor = Color.WHITE;
    boolean removedPanel = false;

    public void launchFrame() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
            arrx[x] = rand.nextInt(640);
            arry[x] = rand.nextInt(590);
            rectanglesList.add(new Rectangle(arrx[x], arry[x], 80, 90));
        }

        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();

        JPanel panelsPane = new JPanel() {
            public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                super.paintComponent(g);

//              Image img = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Rectangles2.class.getResource("background.jpg"));
//              g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight(), this);
                Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

                for (Rectangle s : rectanglesList) {
                    g2.setColor(bColor);
                    g2.fill(s);
                    g2.setColor(wColor);
                    g2.draw(s);
                }
            }
        };

        JPanel rightPane = new JPanel();

        panelsPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
                x = event.getX();
                y = event.getY();
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
                // Because the rectangles are painted in order, the later
                // rectangles are painted over the eailer ones, so, we reverse
                // the list so we can check for the higher positioned
                // rectangles
                List<Rectangle> copy = new ArrayList<>(rectanglesList);
                Collections.reverse(copy);
                for (Rectangle r : copy) {
                    if (r.contains(event.getPoint())) {
                        rectanglesList.remove(r);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                event.getComponent().repaint();
            }
        });

        panelsPane.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
            }

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
            }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent event) {
            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent event) {
            }
        });

        panelsPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, ySize - 315));
        rightPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(530, ySize - 315));
        mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(xSize, ySize));
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(xSize, ySize));
        rightPane.setBackground(Color.gray);
        mainPanel.add(panelsPane);
        mainPanel.add(rightPane);
        frame.add(mainPanel);

        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                Rec obj = new Rec();
                obj.launchFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool! Thank you for this! I will study the logic very well. :)

Comment: Problem though. The rectangles are all  colored black?

Comment: Yep, `Rectangle` doesn't carry color information.  If you need color, then I'd probably create a custom class (maybe called `Box`), which carried the color and `Rectangle` information.  Basically, it would act as a light wrapper around these values, making it easier to associate them together.  Of course, you could also use a `Map` of some kind

Comment: Okay I'll try exploring from here! Thanks :)